# Lake Misurina from Bolzano

Tags: trains, italy, buses, dolomites

Is there any efficient and convenient way of traveling (only by public transport) from Bolzano to Lake Misurina? Or should I travel to Venice first from Bolzano?

I found this route: Is there any public transport along the Grande Strada Delle Dolomiti from Bolzano to Cortina d'Ampezzo?

Comment: I answered with the route I found now. I'll try to add more info tomorrow, if I can find something cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bolzano/Misurina) suggests the following route:

> Bolzano/Bozen - Fortezza/Franzensfeste (train, 43min, hourly)
> Fortezza/Franzensfeste - Dobbiaco-Stazione (train, 1h 15min, every 30 minutes)
> Dobbiaco-Stazione - Misurina-Genzianella (bus 444, 23 min, every 3 hours)
>
> 9-33€ / 3h 40 min

An [alternative](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bolzano/Cortina-d-Ampezzo) would be to go to Cortina d'Ampezzo and take the bus from there.

Comment: From Toblach you could also take bus 445 to Schluderbach and have a 6 km hike.
It also looks like 444 ran at least every hour during summer season 2018.

Answer (score 2):

[Trenitalia](http://www.trenitalia.com) (main italian train player) changed their website again and looks like it's impossible to find any cheap solution. (they force you to use high speed high priced trains)

It will take about 6 hours and 56 € to get **near** Misurina lake.

Your travel plan is:

> **Bolzano Bozen** -to- Verona Porta Nuova
>   Verona Porta Nuova -to- Venezia Mestre (**do not** arrive to Venezia, this is the station before)
>   Venezia Mestre -to- **Cortina d'Ampezzo**

From Cortina d'Ampezzo you may catch a local bus to Misurina.

Comment: I found this route: Is there any public transport along the Grande Strada Delle Dolomiti from Bolzano to Cortina d'Ampezzo?

Comment: I wouldn't say that Cortina is near Misurina, unless you call short a 14 km road climbing passo Tre Croci (600 m gradient). Anyway the train from Venice takes you to Calalzo, 34 km from Cortina. There are buses from Calalzo to Misurina (via Auronzo).